# unable to set view permissions for custom user in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am using `role-based strategy` for authorization in `jenkins`.
I created user `Developer` and create `role` named `developer`

[image]

I assigned `developer` user to `developer` group

[image]

But when I am trying to access jenkins using `developer` user I get

[image]

What is the problem?